# PhpStorm - Is there a way to transform PHPDoc to type-hint and return type-declaration?

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-7, type-hinting, type-declaration

Is there a way in PhpStorm to transform PHPDoc to type-hint and return type-declaration?

E.g. transform...

```
/**
 * @param float $coefficient
 * @return $this
 */
public function setCoefficient($coefficient)
{
    $this->coefficient = (float) $coefficient;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return float
 */
public function getCoefficient()
{
    return $this->coefficient;
}
```

...to

```
public function setCoefficient(float $coefficient): self
{
    $this->coefficient = (float) $coefficient;

    return $this;
}

public function getCoefficient(): float
{
    return $this->coefficient;
}
```

---

Filltext: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: There might be better tools like Rector for that

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/dunglas/phpdoc-to-typehint

Before:

```
<?php

/**
 * @param int|null $a
 * @param string   $b
 *
 * @return float
 */
function bar($a, $b, bool $c, callable $d = null)
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

After:

```
<?php

/**
 * @param int|null $a
 * @param string   $b
 *
 * @return float
 */
function bar(int $a = null, string $b, bool $c, callable $d = null) : float
{
    return 0.0;
}
```